# Change cursor position in the contenteditable div after changing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, cursor-position

I have a simple contenteditable div with some text in it.
On onkeyup event i want to replace whole content (innerHTML) of the div based on regex.

For example,

HTML:

```
some text, more text and $even more text
```

Function in which i plan to get all text with $ ($even in example above) and wrap it in span tag:

```
div.onkeypress = function() { 
     div.innerHTML.replace(/(some_regexp)/, "<span class='class'>$1</span>"); 
};
```

The problem is after such replacement cursor jumps to the start of the div. I want it to stay where it was before.

I imagine i have to save coordinates of the cursor before change and then somehow using them set cursor back but how can i do it? :)

I tried saving range object but after editing i believe it points to nowhere.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the replacement HTML look like?

Comment: I've updated the original question. if you know how to get expected behavior by some other means without changing whole innerHTML - would be great to hear.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but did you managed to find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same need

Answer (score 3):

I took this from another forum. It solved my problem.

Ok, I managed to work around it, here's the solution if anyone's interested:

Store the selection x, y:

Code:

```
cursorPos=document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
clickx = cursorPos.getBoundingClientRect().left; 
clicky = cursorPos.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Restore the selection:

Code:

```
cursorPos = document.body.createTextRange();
cursorPos.moveToPoint(clickx, clicky);
cursorPos.select();
```

You can see it working here:

http://www.tachyon-labs.com/sharpspell/

Comment: Am i missing something? Followed the link, selected Live demo. Clicked in the middle of the word, right click, selected option and cursor jumped to the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're updating the whole innerHTML, but only a small part of it is changing. You can't use a regular expression and o a bulk replace. You need to scan the div and look for matches, create text ranges out of them and wrap the content with the span. See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html , Programmatically creating a Range.

However, I think this won't work if the cursor is in the text to be replaced, it's a start though.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but even though I used range the caret position returns back to the start of the div.

Comment: @carmina Hard to tell if you don't show your code. However, if you have a question, please ask it as a new question (with the code you used), so it can be addressed properly

Comment: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262798/using-insertnode-to-add-a-span-in-a-contenteditable-div-changes-the-cursor-posit

Answer (score 1):

You know which text you are replacing. So you know the position of that text . there only you going to put the new text. Then also the position is same.After writing new html , yu can set cursor.

for eg

I dont undertsand the question

position of question is 5 an i replace it

I dont undertsand the answer

make the cursor position to 5

http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-tip-cross-browser-cursor-positioning

http://hartshorne.ca/2006/01/23/javascript_cursor_position/

http://geekswithblogs.net/svanvliet/archive/2005/03/24/textarea-cursor-position-with-javascript.aspx